# Magento: Add Widget tool onto product and category WYSIWYG

Tags: magento, content-management-system, widget, wysiwyg

On the WYSIWYG editor for CMS pages in Magento there's a tool to add Magento widgets to the editor. I'd like this also to be available for the WYSIWYG on the product and category descriptions.

I'm struggling to find where the editor is even loaded at the moment. Could anyone let me know what I might have to do or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content there are two flags in the config array 'add_widgets' and 'add_variables'. Both of these are set to false by default.

Setting these to true will then be caught in the Mage_Widget_Model_Observer class function prepareWidgetsPluginConfig on the event cms_wysiwyg_config_prepare.

I would suggest rewriting the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content to fit your needs, but setting add_widgets and add_variables to true should work for both categories and products.

Comment: Just tried this and although it adds the buttons in the WYSIWYG editor perfectly and appears to function as expected, it didn't render properly in the front end (just shows the widget code as opposed to converting to links).

Answer (score 7):

After enabling `add_widgets` and `add_variables` in class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content` as per @David Manner's answer, you will likely find that whilst this will certainly enable these in the WYSIWYG editor and function properly, it will only render the raw widget/variable code in the front end (rather than the appropriate markup).

You can fix with the following:-

Navigate to `/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

Find `<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>`

Add the following below this line:-

```
<?php 
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms'); 
    $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor(); 
    $_description = $processor->filter($_description); 
?>
```

This will render in the frontend correctly then.

Comment: My above example is for the category pages but you can equally implement on product pages in the product view template.

Comment: This appears to no longer work on Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

After read all answers I found elegant solution. This solution rewrite only one Block class and doesn't change any template file.

1. Rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content

   `<config>
       ...
       <global>
           <blocks>
               ...
               <adminhtml>
                   <rewrite>
   <catalog_helper_form_wysiwyg_content>Agere_Wysiwyg_Block_Widget_Anywhere</catalog_helper_form_wysiwyg_content>
                   </rewrite>
               </adminhtml>
           </blocks>
           ...
       </global>
   </config>`
2. Change only two flags in the config array 'add_widgets' and 'add_variables' to true

   ```
   class Agere_Wysiwyg_Block_Widget_Anywhere extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg_Content {
       protected function _prepareForm() {
           //return parent::_prepareForm();
           $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'wysiwyg_edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'));

           $config['document_base_url']     = $this->getData('store_media_url');
           $config['store_id']              = $this->getData('store_id');
           $config['add_variables']         = true;
           $config['add_widgets']           = true;
           $config['add_directives']        = true;
           $config['use_container']         = true;
           $config['container_class']       = 'hor-scroll';

           $form->addField($this->getData('editor_element_id'), 'editor', array(
               'name'      => 'content',
               'style'     => 'width:725px;height:460px',
               'required'  => true,
               'force_load' => true,
               'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig($config)
           ));
           $this->setForm($form);

           return $this;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create handler that will process content from category or product

   ```
   class Agere_Wysiwyg_Helper_Filter extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
       public function categoryAttribute($mainHelper, $result, $params) {
           return $this->process($result);
       }

       public function productAttribute($mainHelper, $result, $params) {
           return $this->process($result);
       }

       public function process($result) {
           /** @var Mage_Cms_Helper_Data $helperCms */
           $helperCms = Mage::helper('cms');
           $processor = $helperCms->getPageTemplateProcessor();

           return $processor->filter($result);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally create Observer wich add handlers for out wysiwyg

   ```
   class Agere_Wysiwyg_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
       public function addWysiwygHandler(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
           /** @var Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output $_helperOutput */
           /** @var Agere_Wysiwyg_Helper_Filter $_helperFilter */
           $_helperOutput = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
           $_helperFilter = Mage::helper('agere_wysiwyg/filter');
           $_helperOutput->addHandler('categoryAttribute', $_helperFilter);
           $_helperOutput->addHandler('productAttribute', $_helperFilter);
       }
   }
   ```

Full snap of code see by link https://github.com/popovsergiy/magento-wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

Think a better way is to create a new observer that listening on the same event, and make the module depending on Mage_Widget. Then our observer will be running after Mage_Widget